# Duplicating result in Out-GridView [The property 'Installed' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists and can be set.]?

Tags: powershell

The below script was working fine to search and check particular patches of installation information in the list of servers (Domain Controllers).

```
Clear-Host
$hotFixesID = @('KB4571694','KB4056890')
$computerList = Get-ADComputer -LDAPFilter "(&(objectCategory=computer)(userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=8192))" | Where-Object { Test-Connection $_.Name -Count 1 -Quiet } | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name
$properties = 'PSComputerName', 'HotFixID', 'Installed', 'Description', 'InstalledBy', 'InstalledOn', 'Exception'
$computerList | ForEach-Object {
    Write-Host "Processing Server $($_) ..." -ForegroundColor Cyan
    Foreach ($hotFixID in $hotFixesID) {
        Write-Host "`tProcessing Server $($_) Hotfix ID $($hotFixID)..." -ForegroundColor Yellow
        $out = $exception = $null
        Try {
            $out = Get-WmiObject -Query "Select * From Win32_QuickFixEngineering Where HotFixID='$($hotFixID)'" -ComputerName $_ -ErrorAction Stop | Select-Object -Property $properties
        }
        Catch {
            $exception = $_.Exception.Message
        }
        If ($out) {
            $out.Installed = $true
        }
        Else {
            $out = '' | Select-Object -Property $properties
            $out.PSComputerName = $_
            $out.HotFixID = $hotFixID
            If ($exception) {
                $out.Exception = $exception
            }
            Else {
                $out.Installed = $false
            }
        }
        $out
    }
} | OGV
```

How can I fix the minor issue where the Installed Hotfix result is duplicated?

Error:

```
The property 'Installed' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists and can be set.
At line:17 char:13
+             $out.Installed = $true
+             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyAssignmentException
```

Comment: I’m curious, where do you get these scripts? It’s clear you’re not the author of any of them. What makes you think there is duplicates? The error message doesn’t indicate that issue.

Comment: you are resetting the `$Out` var inside your `try` block. try setting that to `$Null` before the `try` scriptblock.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey, yes, I have updated the code by moving the $out = $exception = $null before the try catch, the error is still the same.

Comment: @DougMaurer, this script was created and adjusted from my predecessor, so it was not a whole script from one famous author.
Anyway, the script has a minor issue that I need some help to fix when the KB patch installed in a server, the OGV result is duplicated?

Comment: Well some of them are quite interesting.

Comment: @SeniorSystemsEngineer - arg! i see that DougMaurer posted a neatened-up version that handles things quite handily. good! [*grin*]

Comment: No problem, @Lee_Dailey

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK I found the script to be cumbersome and hard to debug. I've rewritten it with more consideration of what to output when the call doesn't fail but the KB is not installed.

```
 $computerlist = Get-ADComputer -LDAPFilter "(&(objectCategory=computer)(userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=8192))" | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name

$computerList | ForEach-Object {
    Write-Host "Processing Server $_ ..." -ForegroundColor Cyan
    Foreach ($hotFixID in $hotFixesID) {
        Write-Host "`tProcessing Server $_ Hotfix ID $hotFixID..." -ForegroundColor Yellow

        Try
        {
            $result = Get-WmiObject -Query "Select * From Win32_QuickFixEngineering Where HotFixID='$hotFixID'" -ComputerName $_ -ErrorAction Stop
            $exception   = "No error"

            if($result)
            {
                $installed = $true
                $description = $result.description
                $installedBy = $result.installedby
                $installedOn = $result.installedon
            }
            else
            {
                $installed = $false
                $description = "N/A"
                $installedBy = "N/A"
                $installedOn = "N/A"
            }
        }
        Catch {
            $exception = $_.Exception.Message
        }

        [PSCustomObject]@{
            PSComputerName = $_
            HotFixID       = $hotFixID
            Installed      = $installed
            Description    = $description
            InstalledBy    = $installedBy
            InstalledOn    = $installedon
            Exception      = $exception
        }
    }
} | Out-GridView
```

Comment: thank you so much, you've made my day, it is working great and I learn from this solution you've proposed.